# jQuery multiple firing submit form event (I think)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have got this form:

```html
<li class="easyad_form_li">Pro tento článek ještě lze zakoupit reklamu - <a class="easyad_showform_link" onclick="$(\'#easyad_gateway_form\').toggle(\'normal\')">zobrazit formulář pro nákup</a>
<form id="easyad_gateway_form" action="' . EASYAD_GATEWAY_LINK . '?a=checkout" METHOD="POST">
   <label for="easyad_gateway_link">Odkaz:</label> <input type="text" name="easyad_gateway_link" value="http://">* <i>(uveďte včetně http://)</i><br />
   <label for="easyad_gateway_link_name">Název: </label> <input type="text" name="easyad_gateway_link_name">* <i>(bude zobrazeno jako klikatelný odkaz)</i><br />
   <label for="easyad_gateway_desc">Popisek:</label> <input type="text" name="easyad_gateway_desc">* <i>(bude zobrazeno za odkazem, neklikatelné)</i><br />
   <span class="easyad_box_req">Pole označená hvězdičkou je nutné vyplnit!</span><br />
   <input type="hidden" name="id_post" id="id_post" value="' . get_the_ID() . '">
   <input type="submit" name="wd_submit" id="wd_submit" class="button action" value="Zaplatit WD">
   <input type="image" name="paypal_submit" id="paypal_submit"  src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_dg_pay_w_paypal.gif" border="0" align="top" alt="Pay with PayPal" />
</form>
```

If you click on PayPal button as first, form working normally. And if you click on second button (submit - `#wd_submit`) its working normally too. But if you click on submit button and then on PayPal button, it show 2 new window (1st with PayPal data and 2nd blank).

I think, that problem may be in my jQuery code (I am unskilled in jQuery).

Here is the code:

```js
$('#wd_submit').click(function (event){
    $('#easyad_gateway_form').submit(function(event) {
        window.open('', 'formpopup', 'width=292,height=365,scrollbars=no');
        this.target = 'formpopup';              
    });  
});
```

Thanks for all tips, tricks and help posts :)

Comment: Add `event.preventDefault()` after `$('#wd_submit').click(function (event){`

Comment: @PatsyIssa with `event.preventDefault()` my jQuery code not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the click handler, since the `wd_submit` button is of type submit it will trigger the form submit event, you can just listen to that

```
$('#easyad_gateway_form').submit(function (event) {
    window.open('', 'formpopup', 'width=292,height=365,scrollbars=no');
    this.target = 'formpopup';
});
```

In your case whenever the user click on the button a new submit handler is getting registered, so when the user clicks the first time there is one handler but when he clicks again there are 2 handlers added now and both of the will get triggered

Adding a event handler inside another one is always dangerous and you have to be very careful with that.

Comment: did you remove the click handler

Comment: Yes, now I have got only 1 handler -> submit. If you want, you can see this problem in this page -> [Test web page](http://pes502.cz/test/ead/?p=1) If you click on "zobrazit formulář pro nákup" under post, you will see 2 buttons. "Zaplatit WD" working correctly, PayPal still not working. The .js file with this my jQuery code is here - [My jQuery file](http://pes502.cz/test/ead/wp-content/plugins/easyad/webdeal_lib/WDConnect.js)

Comment: @pes502 in which file you have added the script

Comment: @pes502 where is the script related to `paypal_submit`?

Comment: PayPal using [this script](https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js) I wanna something like "do submit event only when `#wd_submit` clicked"

Comment: in which file you have the form submit handler

Comment: [HERE](http://pes502.cz/test/ead/wp-content/plugins/easyad/webdeal_lib/WDConnect.js) and it's included in `<head>`

Comment: ok.. I think the problem is the paypal click also is triggering the form submit.... so try `$('#wd_submit').click(function (event) {
    window.open('_blank', 'formpopup', 'width=292,height=365,scrollbars=no');
    this.target = 'formpopup';
    return false;
});`

Comment: Yea, this working fine, but I need open a `<form action="">` url in this new window. Your code show blank window. I was written this jQuery (found snippet on stackoverflow) code coz I need pass the form variables into new window :/

Comment: in that case retain the last script and try adding `$('#paypal_submit').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
})`

Comment: I was found the solution! I was added this code: `$('#paypal_submit').click(function (event) {event.preventDefault();});` into my .js file and its working correctly now! :P

Comment: @pes502 yes that is the correct one... I used `stopPropagation()` by mistake... you have to use it along with the previous change